# ActiveSupport TimeZone not returning all zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql-ruby

I'm having an issue like [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7245). Not all zones are returning with:

```rb
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.sort_by {|t| t.name}.map { |tz|
  #symbol = tz.tzinfo.identifier.gsub(/[^_a-zA-Z0-9]/, '_').squeeze('_').upcase!
  
  tz.to_s #> (GMT+00:00) Edinburgh for example
}
```

I need to use the `.to_s` to get the UTC `(GMT+00:00)`. With the above, `London` is missing and I assume others. This one works great:

```rb
ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.sort_by {|k,v| k}.map { |k,v|
  #symbol = k.gsub(/[^_a-zA-Z0-9]/, '_').squeeze('_').upcase!
  
  k #> London London is included with this method
}
```

I cannot use this method because I do not know how to get the `(GMT+00:00)` in `(GMT+00:00) London`

Has the bug return? How to get all the zones show for the first example?

Edit.

I'm using [GraphQL-ruby](https://graphql-ruby.org/). I've created an enum to return a list of time zones:

```rb
# Taken from: https://gist.github.com/pedrocarmona/f41d25e631c1144045971c319f1c9e17
class Types::TimeZoneEnumType < Types::BaseEnum
  ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.sort_by {|t| t.name}.map { |tz|
    symbol = tz.tzinfo.identifier.gsub(/[^_a-zA-Z0-9]/, '_').squeeze('_').upcase
    value("TZ_#{symbol}", tz.to_s)
  }
end
```

Then inside `query_type.rb`

```rb
[..]

field :time_zones, Types::TimeZoneEnumType, null: false

[..]
```

Next, inside graphiql, I make the query:

```js
query timeZones{
  __type(name: "TimeZoneEnum") {
    enumValues {
      name
      description
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns something like, except London:

```json
[
  [..]

  {
    "name": "TZ_AMERICA_LA_PAZ",
    "description": "(GMT-04:00) La Paz"
  },
  {
    "name": "TZ_AMERICA_LIMA",
    "description": "(GMT-05:00) Lima"
  },
  {
    "name": "TZ_EUROPE_LISBON",
    "description": "(GMT+00:00) Lisbon"
  },
  {
    "name": "TZ_EUROPE_LJUBLJANA",
    "description": "(GMT+01:00) Ljubljana"
  },
  {
    "name": "TZ_EUROPE_MADRID",
    "description": "(GMT+01:00) Madrid"
  },
  
  [..]
]
```

After `Ljubljana` I should see "London" but it's not there.

Comment: What version of Rails are you running? When I run `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:to_s)` in Rails 6.1, London is included.

You're sorting by the name field, but mapping to `to_s` which includes the timezone, so I wonder if you just missed London in the ouput?

Comment: Running that code I get `(GMT+00:00) London` included as well

Comment: It's weird. OK me have a look again.

Comment: It shows in the console but not rendering. I'll explain exactly what I'm doing in the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I run

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.sort_by {|t| t.name}.map { |tz| 
  [ tz.tzinfo.identifier.gsub(/[^_a-zA-Z0-9]/, '_').squeeze('_').upcase, tz.to_s ] 
}.sort
```

the result includes the entries `["EUROPE_LONDON", "(GMT+00:00) Edinburgh"], ["EUROPE_LONDON", "(GMT+00:00) London"]`, i.e. `EUROPE_LONDON` is duplicated.

I don't know how the GraphQL library is operating, but I'm  assuming it's deduplicating the data and returning a single entry for `EUROPE_LONDON` (enums are normally unique). Moscow is the same - it has values for Moscow and St Petersburg - so you could test by looking at the results for `EUROPE_MOSCOW`.